# lftp mirror error

Tags: linux, bash, lftp

I have a problem with a script that I am trying to write.

Ideally, the script should compress the folders and then send the zipped files to the ftp server creating the folder as the name of the zipped file (without extension) but it's not working correctly quite yet, what am I doing wrong ?

Hi, the manually executed script returns this error

mirror: Access failed: 530 Access denied (.zip)

I would like to send the files that zipped to the ftp server, what should I change? Thank you

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST=""
USER=""
PWD=""
FILESIZE="$(du -sm $1 | cut -f1)"
ZIPNAME="$(basename $1)"
REMOTEFOLDER="$(dirname $1)"

if [ $FILESIZE -ge 1500 ]
then
        7z a -v1400m $REMOTEFOLDER/$ZIPNAME.zip $1
else
        7z a $REMOTEFOLDER/$ZIPNAME.zip $1
fi

lftp ftp://$USER:$PWD@$HOST -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; mirror -R -r -i '$ZIPNAME.zip*' $REMOTEFOLDER /$REMOTEFOLDER; quit"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to unix.se! Impressive first question, too, but it's still missing a few things. You've explained what you *want* your script to accomplish pretty well, but what you haven't mentioned is what's actually happening and in which way it's failing. Does the `lftp` command return any errors? What happens differently if you attempt to run the `lftp` part manually instead?

Comment: (We can discuss lftp bookmarks, saved passwords and the extreme inadvisability of using passwords on a command line visible with `ps axe` at a later date as it's *probably* not germane to the reason why your script isn't working.

Comment: Hi, the manually executed script returns this error

mirror: Access failed: 530 Access denied (.zip)

Comment: Please add that to the question proper rather than comments. It looks like it's not generating the filenames properly because it refuses to let you mirror a file named ".zip" which *probably* isn't what you wanted to happen...

Comment: Another thing you can try is running the script with `sh -x`. This will echo each command before it's executed, and may help catch quoting errors. Perhaps what you *think* it's sending isn't quite what's going on.